# How do I set a session variable(an int for the User's ID) after a person logs in using j_security_check in a Java servlet?

Tags: java, session, jsp, servlets

I want to store the the user's ID in a session variable to use across the application. I don't see how I'd do that with the default security feature? It authenticates itself and I don't know (if) there is a callback function or something? That we can use to do our house-keeping

Any help is deeply appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`Filter`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) for this which checks if the user is logged in by container managed security (i.e. [`HttpServletRequest#getUserPrincipal()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getUserPrincipal%28%29) doesn't return `null`) and then sets the session variable if not present.

Basically:

```
if (request.getUserPrincipal() != null && session.getAttribute("user") == null) {
    session.setAttribute("userId", userId);
}
```

However, maybe you don't need to do it at all since it proves that you aren't aware about `HttpServletRequest#getUserPrincipal()`. It may namely already offer exactly the information you need. The login username (it may be the same as the user ID where you're talking about) is available by [`Principal#getName()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/Principal.html#getName%28%29).

Comment: Yes the book I was referring to does not go into that. Most of my sql queries have foreign keys with the users ID so thats why I wanted to do it. I get the idea though, filter that sets the users id. Thanks i'll look into it